# Knockout- Issues editing item with pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Im new to knockout and loving it so far. I've been trying to build a row editing grid using a simple table with edit links. So far it seemed to be going great but been stuck on this issue where im getting the errors when tying to save and update or canel:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.description is not a function
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.editdescription is not a function
```

Been staring at the code for several hours now can't seem to wrap my head around this one. I am able to replicate the issue in this JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/N2zNk/49/

Would anyone know what is cloging in my code?

Here is my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'rowTmpl', foreach: products }"></tbody>
</table>

<script id="rowTmpl" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Composante"></td>
        <td>
            <a href="#dialogEditProduct" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" data-bind="click: $parent.editProduct">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { viewModel.removeItem($data); }">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>

    <!-- popup -->
    <div id="dialogEditProduct" style="width: 400px; max-width: 100%;" data-role="popup" data-theme="c" data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false" data-bind="with: selectedProduct">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
             <h1 ></h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
            <p>
                <label>Description:</label>
                <input data-bind="value: editDescription" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Composante:</label>
                <input data-bind="value: editComposante" />
            </p>
            <button data-role="button" data-bind="click: function() { Incidents.pvm.acceptEdit(); }">Save</button>
            <button data-role="button" data-bind="click: function() { Incidents.pvm.cancelEdit() }">Cancel</button>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my code:

```
function Item(ID, Description, Composante) {

    var self = this;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Description = ko.observable(Description);
    this.Composante = ko.observable(Composante);
        this.editDescription = ko.observable(Description);
    this.editComposante = ko.observable(Composante);    

this.accept = function () {
    this.description(this.editdescription); 
  this.price(this.editPrice);
    return true;
}.bind(this);
//reset to originals on cancel
this.cancel = function () {
    this.editdescription(this.description);
    this.editComposante(this.Composante);
}.bind(this);

}

Incidents = {
pvm: {},
productStore: {
    products: [],
    init: function (data) {
        this.products = $.map(data, function (product) {
            return new Item(product.ID, product.Description, product.Composante);
        });
    }
},  

init: function () {
/*emuluate pulling orders from DB*/
/*this will come from server or local web storage*/
        var dataFromServer = [{
            ID: "123",
            Description: "The server x is unavailable",
            Composante: "CCD"
        }, {
            ID: "124",
            Description: "The router located downtown is down",
            Composante: "CCDD"
        }, {
            ID: "125",
            Description: "Fiber optic cable downtown is flapping",
            Composante: "MIG"
        }, {
            ID: "126",
            Description: "Network unvailable at the beaver site",
            Composante: "MIC"
        }];

  this.productStore.init(dataFromServer);

  $(function () {
    Incidents.pvm = new Incidents.productViewModel(Incidents.productStore.products);
    ko.applyBindings(Incidents.pvm);
    $("#productList").listview('refresh');
  });  
},
productViewModel: function (data) {
        var self = this;
        var productsArray = [];
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
            productsArray = data;
        }
        this.products = ko.observableArray(productsArray);
        this.selectedProduct = ko.observable();
        this.editProduct = function (productToEdit) {
            self.selectedProduct(productToEdit);

            // Incidents.pvm.selectedProduct(productToEdit);
        };
        this.acceptEdit = function () {
            var selected = Incidents.pvm.selectedProduct();
            if (selected.accept()) {
                Incidents.pvm.selectedProduct("");
                $('#dialogEditProduct').popup('close');
            }
        };
        this.cancelEdit = function () {
            Incidents.pvm.selectedProduct().cancel();
            Incidents.pvm.selectedProduct("");
            $('#dialogEditProduct').popup('close');
        };
    }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.jqButton = {
    init: function (element) {
        $(element).button();
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var currentValue = valueAccessor();
        $(element).button("option", "disabled", currentValue.enable === false);
    }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmListView = {
    init: function (element) {
        $(element).listview();
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).listview('refresh');
    }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.openProductDialog = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {  
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            $.mobile.changePage("#dialogEditProduct", {
                role: 'dialog'
            });
            $("#dialogEditProduct").open();    
            // $("#dialogEditProduct").trigger('create');    
        }

    }
};

$.extend({
    isNumber: function (obj) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(obj)) && isFinite(obj);
    }
});

Incidents.init();
```

Comment: You have a mis-match between `this.Description` and `this.description`

Comment: In addition, I think you're missing the `()` off some of your observables, eg `this.Description(this.editDescription())` - note extra brackets at the end.  You want to pass the value of the observable, not the observable itself.

Comment: Thank you guys, I noticed it after I posted this. You guys made my day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. You have mixed up `description` and `Description`. Also, `editDescription` and `editdescription`.

Comment: That did the trick thank you Crimson and everybody else. For those curios here is the working JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/N2zNk/50/.